# Close SQL Connection from VB.net MVC 3.5 - Timeout issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, timeout, connection

I've gone over a lot of the posts on here for help with this issue but none of suggestions seem to be helping close my SQL connections.

This is the function that I am using in VB.net:

```
Private Function InsertOtherProjectMembers(ByVal inProjectRequestId, ByVal inEmployeeId, ByVal inEmployee) As Boolean
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = objDataClass.Create_Connection()
        cmd.CommandText = "usp_InsertOtherProjectMember"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectRequestId", inProjectRequestId)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", inEmployeeId)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", inEmployee)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        reader.Close()
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Using

End Function
```

I just recently added the Using - End Using because of ideas I found on here. I also added reader.Close, cmd.Connection.Close, cmd.Dispose.
Before the code was in a Try-Catch-Finally.

Everytime this code is run it is adding Employees to a database in a loop, so it does an insert for each employee, opening a connection to the database for each employee. the list of employees being added can be quite long, sometimes 30-40 employees.

I am trying to close the connections after they have been created because once the user does a save and tries to load anything else in the application, we get an SQL error stating that there are too many connections to the Database. When I run `sp_who` on the DB it shows me an incremental amount of connections to the DB, initially it can be 2 or 3, which include the login and loading initial data, but after I run this Insert it goes up to 15 and then to 20ish and then into the 30's. It's always creating new connections and never closing the old ones.

This is the SQL code that is being called for usp_InsertOtherProjectMember

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertOtherProjectMember]
@ProjectRequestId Varchar(50),
@EmployeeId varchar(5),
@Employee varchar(50)
AS

-- Get the integer part of the transmitted request number
Declare @inReqId AS Int
SET @inReqId = Substring(@ProjectRequestId, 3, Len(@ProjectRequestId)-2) 


Insert Into tblProjectRequestOtherMembers(ProjectRequestId, EmployeeId, Employee) 
Values(@inReqId, @EmployeeId, @Employee)
```

Is there anything else I should add / change in my code to close the connections? Currently the connections are only being closed by the Garbage Collector, eventually....

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
Adding code for Create_Connection()

```
Public Function Create_Connection() As Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = ConnectionString
    Dim Conn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConn)
    Conn.Open()
    Create_Connection = Conn
End Function
```

ConnectionString is being taken from Webconfig and is defined as a public variable:

```
ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

In webconfig:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=*SERVERNAME*;Database=*DATABASENAME*;Trusted_Connection=True"/>
```

Also I want to add that this is code that I have inherited and I am trying to patch it up....

Comment: `SET @inReqId = Substring(@ProjectRequestId, 3, Len(@ProjectRequestId)-2) ` that's bad. Make `@ProjectRequestId` an `Int` type, then you don't have to do all that non-sence. Also please post `objDataClass.Create_Connection()` the code for that... `objDataClass.Create_Connection()` that object instance is your problem, it has a pointer to that connection (object)...

Comment: I've made an edit to my code with the missing function...thanks for the reply!

Comment: I know this is not the answer but could you not do the following... Create connection.... loop through additions and then close/dispose connection once all additions in loop completed? A much more efficient method then opening and closing after each addition.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a shot...

```
Public Shared Function Create_Connection() As String
    Return ConnectionString 'Just return the connection string...
End Function

Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
  Using con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(Create_Connection())
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = con 'use the con which is your connection now...
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_InsertOtherProjectMember"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectRequestId", inProjectRequestId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", inEmployeeId)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", inEmployee)

            con.Open()
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            reader.Close()
            con.Close()
  End Using
End Using
```